# Draw text on top of rectangle

Tags: html, canvas, drawing

I'm trying to draw some text in the corner of a rectangle but I just started off drawing text on a rectangle before tackling the positioning. I can't seem to draw a rectangle, fill it with a color and then draw text over it. Even if i draw the text first, then rectangle, then fill in those orders, the rectangle just seems to overlap the text.

This code will show text and rectangles with no fill

```js
context.beginPath();
    
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    context.font = "18pt Arial";
    context.fillText("blah", 0, 0 + (i * 50));
    context.rect(30, 0 + (i * 50), 50, 50);
}
    
context.lineWidth = 0.1;
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();
```

This code will show me the text and filled in rectangles but the text seems to appear below the rectangles.

```js
context.beginPath();
    
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   context.font = "18pt Arial";
   context.fillText("blah", 0, 0 + (i * 50));
   context.rect(30, 0 + (i * 50), 50, 50);
}
    
context.fillStyle = "#33cc00";
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 0.1;
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every paint operation on an HTML5 Canvas draws on top of and (in general) obliterates whatever was underneath. If you want text to draw on top of the rectangles, you must call `fillText()` *after* you call `fill()` for the rects you have created.

It doesn't matter what order drawing commands are added to the path, it is when the `fill()` occurs that determines when the instantly-drying ink is applied. Since you do this after all your `fillText()` calls, the rectangles are drawn on top.

I would modify your code like this:

```js
context.font = "18pt Arial";
context.strokeStyle = "#000";
context.lineWidth = 0.1;
for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {
   context.fillStyle = "#3c0";
   context.fillRect(30, 0 + (i * 50), 50, 50);
   context.strokeRect(30, 0 + (i * 50), 50, 50);
   context.fillStyle = "#fff";
   context.fillText("blah", 0, 0 + (i * 50));
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `fillRect()`/`strokeRect()`:

```js
context.font = "18pt Arial";
context.strokeStyle = "#000";
context.lineWidth = 0.1;
for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {
   context.beginPath();
   context.fillStyle = "#3c0";
   context.rect(30, 0 + (i * 50), 50, 50);
   context.fill();
   context.stroke();

   context.fillStyle = "#fff";
   context.fillText("blah", 0, 0 + (i * 50));
}
```

Comment: perfect just what i needed. i was getting a bit confused with the "layering" as it wasn't filling in the correct order. thanks